# JavaScript: Prevent setInterval Function From Running Until Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, setinterval

New to JS. I am trying to add a button to my page that says, "Start Game". When clicked, a countdown timer function starts executing, changing the text on the button every second from 10 down to 0, at which point the button will say "Time's Up!"

I have used the `setInterval` method to get the countdown timer working, but it starts running as soon as the page loads (run code snippet below to see in action).

I am trying to prevent it from running until the button is clicked. Here is my html button (with the property `"onclick="startTimer()"`), and the JS:

```js
var timeleft = 10
var gameTimer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
function startTimer () {
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(gameTimer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft;  
    }
    timeleft -=1;
};
```

```html
<button id="countdown" onclick="startTimer()">Start Game</button>
```

I have tried adding a `preventDefault` to stop it from running on load, but nothing changed. How can I prevent the function from running until it hears the click event?

Comment: Just have the listener you attach do the `setInterval(startTimer, 1000);` instead of calling it immediately??

Comment: Do not setInterval until the button is clicked. So move it inside the `startTimer` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the answer here is to move the invocation of `setInterval()` inside the function that's called when your button is clicked.

However, you really should re-factor this code a bit, both for readability as well as function. For example, I would expect `startTimer()` to do exactly what it says it does - *start* the timer, nothing more. However it seems that this function handles the decrement of `timeleft`.

The reason the suggestions in the comments above may not make sense at the moment is because you don't want to call `setInterval()` every time you want to decrease `timeleft`. Break this functionality out into discrete functions and save yourself the headache.

```js
var timeleft = 10
var gameTimer;

function startTimer() {
  gameTimer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
};

function tick() {
  if (timeleft <= 0) {
    clearInterval(gameTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft;
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="countdown" onclick="startTimer()">Start Game</button>
```

Comment: Also, thanks for your advice about refactoring the code to be more understandable. As is usually the case, I originally had the startTimer function doing just that, but when it wasn’t working I started changing things all around, trying different ways of doing things until startTimer didn’t start the timer anymore but I just left all my original function names out of laziness >_<